# Is there a CPAN module that digests a short string into a short number?

Tags: perl, hash, module, md5, cpan

I need to create unique numerical ids for some short strings.

```
some.domain.com    -> 32423421
another.domain.com -> 23332423
yet.another.com    -> 12131232
```

Is there a Perl CPAN module that will do something like this?

I've tried using Digest::MD5 but the resulting numbers are too long:

```
some.domain.com    -> 296800572457176150356613937260800159845
```

Answer (score 16):

Just take the first 8 digits of the MD5 hash. This works because **MD5 is *uniformly distributed* over its hash address space**. This means that any consecutive sequence of MD5 hash digits will itself be a uniformly distributed hash.

Alternatively, just use some other uniformly-distributed hashing mechanism that returns 8 numbers. Whatever's easiest for you.

Comment: but then the probability of a collision goes up?

Comment: That's right, but your probability of a collision always goes up when you reduce the address space. You'd have precisely the same problem using a shorter hash no matter how it's created.

Answer (score 4):

Either [Digest::CRC](http://search.cpan.org/~olimaul/Digest-CRC-0.14/lib/Digest/CRC.pm) or [String::CRC32](http://search.cpan.org/~soenke/String-CRC32-1.4/CRC32.pod). The first gives you option to calculate 8-, 16- and 32-bit chcecksums, while second only supports 32-bit.

Answer (score 4):

Given the fact that the strings look like a host names, perhaps you will just resolve them to ip, and present the ip as integer?

Kind of like:

```
perl -le 'my $ip = gethostbyname("depesz.com"); my $num = unpack("N", $ip); print $num'
1311657670
```

Comment: What if they all point to the same IP? There are IPs out there that serve some 10 million host names.